# How do I crawl sites that I can't access when I crawl Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

```
import requests

url = "https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    "Referer": "https://cafe.bithumb.com/",
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    response.raise_for_status()

    print(response.text)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print(f"error: {err}")
```

If you connect with Chrome, you can connect well, but you can't connect with Python.
How can I do?

Comment: *"but you can't connect with Python"* - Why not?  What happens when you try?

Comment: More fundamentally, asking how you can access sites you cannot access does not seem logically possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting stalled by cloudflare. Although i could not figure out a way around it using requests, i can advise you to use selenium to achieve your goal :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

try:
    driver.get(url)
    page_source = driver.page_source
    print(page_source)

except Exception as e:
    print(f"error: {e}")

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL `https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9` seems not to work properly.

Try to access it with curl. You see the following internal error:

```
$ curl 'https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9'
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```

Or verbose:

```
$ curl --verbose 'https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9'
* processing: https://cafe.bithumb.com/view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9
*   Trying 2.19.80.112:443...
* Connected to cafe.bithumb.com (2.19.80.112) port 443
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=KR; ST=Seoul; L=Gangnam-Gu; O=Bithumb Korea Co., Ltd.; CN=*.bithumb.com
*  start date: Feb 14 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Feb 14 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "cafe.bithumb.com" matched cert's "*.bithumb.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/2
* h2 [:method: GET]
* h2 [:scheme: https]
* h2 [:authority: cafe.bithumb.com]
* h2 [:path: /view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9]
* h2 [user-agent: curl/8.2.0]
* h2 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1
> GET /view/boards/43?keyword=&noticeCategory=9 HTTP/2
> Host: cafe.bithumb.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
* Connection #0 to host cafe.bithumb.com left intact
curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
```